# Why the same bitwise operations give different results?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, unsigned, signed

Trying to turn off the MSB with all other bits on.

```
unsigned char a = ~0 << 1 >> 1;
printf("a: %d\n", a);

unsigned char b = ~0;
b <<= 1;
b >>= 1;
printf("b: %d\n", b);
```

The printout gives:

```
a: 255
b: 127
```

Comment: Your snippets rely on implementation defined behaviour. And you use the wrong type specifier to `printf` an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Looks to me the operators bind with different priority.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Even adding parenthesis to make the priorities explicit doesn't make any difference.

Comment: ~0 << 1 >> 1 performs the whole operation on int-type numbers (typically 4 bytes), before truncating the result back down to a char (1 byte) at the very end.  But in your b calculation, you truncate at every step along the way.

Comment: The variable needs to be cast to `unsigned char` after left bit shift to produce 127. This gives 127: `unsigned char a = ((unsigned char)(~0 << 1)) >> 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer promotion rules apply.

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

The RHS of the initialization:

```
unsigned char a = ~0 << 1 >> 1;
```

converts `0` to `int`, then does bitwise left and right shifts, and then finally the assignment converts the result to `unsigned char`. This means that the result will be 255 (assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`).  Technically, you have *undefined behaviour*:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>   zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

You would avoid undefined behaviour if you used:

```
unsigned char a = ~0U << 1 >> 1;
```

The 'multiple assignments' version (avoiding undefined behaviour) is equivalent to:

```
unsigned char a = (unsigned char)(~0U << 1) >> 1;
```

which truncates the result of the left shift before re-promoting the type for the right shift, and would yield 127 as the result (still assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`).